# What are special prompt symbols for busybox's sh support?

Tags: shell, prompt, busybox

I want to setup a time prompt on PS1.
But, there is no document about what are symbols the busybox support.

Is there any one know? Here are all which I knew.

```
PS1='\u@\h: \w \$'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BusyBox has two shells, ash and hush. To see which one you have, run `type chdir`: ash has it as a builtin (synonymous with `cd`), hush doesn't. Both have an optional prompt expansion feature. Ash's is enabled by activating the `ASH_EXPAND_PRMT` feature at compile time, while hush requires `FEATURE_EDITING_FANCY_PROMPT`.

When that feature is present, in ash the value of `PS1` is expanded like a double-quoted string: `$foo`, `$(command)` and `` `command` `` constructs are expanded.

Some backslash escapes are processed (in ash, after substitutions). They are a subset of bash's.

- `\!`: line history count
- `\a`: bell
- `\b`: backspace
- `\e`, `\E`: escape
- `\f`: form feed
- `\h`: host name
- `\n`: newline
- `\r`: carriage return
- `\t`: tab
- `\u`: user name (only with `FEATURE_GETUSERNAME_AND_HOMEDIR`)
- `\v`: vertical tab
- `\w`: current directory, with `~` for the home directory (only with `FEATURE_GETUSERNAME_AND_HOMEDIR`)
- `\W`: current directory (unabbreviated)
- `\xHH` or `\XHH` where HH are two hexadecimal digits: a character given by its hex code
- `\[…\]`: the enclosed text doesn't count for width calculation purposes

(If you're looking at the source code, this happens in `parse_and_put_prompt` in `libbb/lineedit.c`.)

Comment: Is there any way to fake this, maybe with printf, if it wasnt compiled in?

Comment: @StevenPenny To fake what? Backslash expansions can be faked with variable and command substitutions, but I think they're both enabled or disabled together. If they're absent, I don't think you can have a variable prompt, except by changing the value of `PS1`.

Comment: Is there a way to know *if* that feature is set? In my router the backslash expansions like `\e`, `\u` and `\w` are working fine, but variables and `$()` are not. BusyBox v1.24.1, ash